# In Powershell, how can a non-admin user run a process as different user and then read the process exit code?

Tags: powershell-5.0

I need to run an executable as a particular user during a build task in Azure Pipelines. To determine whether to fail the build, I need to read that process's exit code.

**I can't run the script from an explicitly administrative session.**

When I view the process handle using the code below, the exit code is always empty. I'm positive that the executable is returning exit codes (it was written in-house).

In addition to the code below, I also tried using $LASTEXITCODE, but it won't be set unless I run the executable directly (as opposed to using Start-Process).

**Is there a way to view the exit code of that process?**

```
$process = Start-Process -FilePath $pathToExe -ArgumentList $argsString -Credential $credential -PassThru 
# I tried waiting like this as well
#while ($process.HasExited -ne $true) {
#    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5        
#}
$process.WaitForExit()
Write-Host "Process exit code: $($process.ExitCode)"
```

An approach similar to the one below can be used to access the exit code of a process started by one user in the context of another, but it requires an Admin session.

```
$scriptBlock = { 
    param($exePath, $exeArgs)
        $process = Start-Process -FilePath $exePath -ArgumentList $exeArgs -PassThru
        $process.WaitForExit()
        return $process.ExitCode
} 
$runAsUserSession = New-PSSession -Credential $credential
$exitCode = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -ArgumentList @($pathToExe, $argsString) -Session $runAsUserSession
Write-Host "Process exit code: $exitCode"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try invoke method:

```
$process = Start-Process -FilePath $pathToExe -ArgumentList $argsString -Credential $credential -PassThru 
$process.WaitForExit()
#while ($process.HasExited -ne $true) {
#    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5        
#}
Write-Host "Process exit code:" $process.ExitCode
```

Comment: The exit code on the process handle is not "visible" to the user initiating the script.